# How to get CSRF token in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am facing an issue with Null CSRF token from the request.

//For getting CSRF token

`Object obj=request.getSession().getAttribute(WebSessionServerCsrfTokenRepository.class.getName() .concat(".CSRF_TOKEN"));`

We have implemented below code for CSRF generating.

**//For generating CSRF token**

```
@Bean
 public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

 http.csrf()
.csrfTokenRepository(new WebSessionServerCsrfTokenRepository())
.requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(getURLsForDisabledCSRF()).and()
.authorizeExchange()
.pathMatchers(ALLOWED_PATHS).permitAll()
.pathMatchers(ALLOWED_METHODS).permitAll()
.anyExchange()
.authenticated().and()
.securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance()).formLogin().disable()
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
.and().csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()));
return http.build();
//.httpBasic().disable().formLogin().disable().build();
}
```

```
  Please help here I am stuck on this issue last 2 weeks.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you google the spring security documentation and read the chapter on CSRF as it will give you all the information you need

Comment: First try with simple configuration like ` http
.authenticated().and()
.securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance()).formLogin().disable()
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
.and().csrf(); `
In JSP, check in META TAG, ` <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />`

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao We have already implemented XSRF-TOKEN generated but unable to fetch token inside the application using HttpServletRequest object as below code.

Object obj=request.getSession().getAttribute(WebSessionServerCsrfTokenRepository.class.getName() .concat(".CSRF_TOKEN"));

Please help to fetch the token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have find the solution for the reading the token from the cookie.

`CsrfToken obj=new CookieCsrfTokenRepository().loadToken(request);`

We have also implement the WebFilter for the XSRF-TOKEN setting in the cookie.

```java
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        String key=CsrfToken.class.getName();
        Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken =null!=exchange.getAttribute(key) ? 
        exchange.getAttribute(key):Mono.empty();
        return csrfToken.doOnSuccess(token->{
            ResponseCookie cookie=ResponseCookie.from("XSRF-TOKEN", token.getToken()).maxAge(Duration.ofHours(1))
                    .httpOnly(false).path("/").build();
            //System.out.println("Cookie {} : "+cookie);
            exchange.getResponse().getCookies().add("XSRF-TOKEN", cookie);
        }).then(chain.filter(exchange));
                
}
```